# If $A_n$ is a countable set for each $n ∈ \Bbb N,$ then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n,$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I was recently, going through a proof of the following theorem, which states that:

If $A_n$ is a countable set for each $n ∈ \Bbb N,$ then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n,$ is countable.

[Definitions that are givem in the book:

> Countable Set: A set  A is  countable iff $\exists $ a bijective mapping $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb A.$

(This means, that we are not considering any finite set/empty set to be countable)]

I was interested in the following way of proving this:

Arranging $\Bbb N$ into the two-dimensional array, we have:
$$\begin{array}{}1& 3& 6&10&15\\
2& 5& 9& 14&\ddots\\
4&8&13&\ddots\\
7&12&\ddots\\
11&\ddots
\end{array}$$

Let’s first consider the case where the sets $\{A_n\}$ are disjoint. In order to achieve $1-1$ correspondence between the set $\Bbb N$ and $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n,$ we first label the
elements in each countable set $A_n$ as $A_n = \{a_{n_1}, a_{n_2}, a_{n_3},...\}.$
Now we arrange the elements of $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ in an array similar to the one for $\Bbb N$ given above:
$$\begin{align}A_1 ={} &a_{11}\space a_{12}\space a_{13}\space a_{14}\space a_{15} \cdots\\
A_2 ={} &a_{21}\space a_{22}\space a_{23}\space a_{24} \cdots\\
A_3 = {}&a_{31}\space a_{32}\space a_{33} \cdots\\
A_4 = {}&a_{41}\space a_{42} \cdots\\
A_5 = {}&a_{51} \cdots\\
&\vdots\end{align}$$

This establishes a $1–1$ and onto mapping $g : N\to\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$  where $g(n)$ corresponds to the element $a_{jk}$ where $(j, k)$ is the row and column location of $n$ in the array for $\Bbb N$ given above.

If the sets $\{A_n\}$ are not disjoint then our mapping may not be $1–1.$ In this case we could again replace $A_n$ with $$B_n = A_n-\{A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_n\}.$$

---

However, I am having some trouble to understand the line of reasoning in the proof, where, it argues  that the above theorem is valid even if all $\{A_n\}$ are not disjoint. This is because, in this proof, it says,

> If the sets $\{A_n\}$ are not disjoint then our mapping may not be $1–1.$ In this case we could again replace $A_n$ with $$B_n = A_n-\{A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_n\}.$$

and this looks kind of an incomplete reasoning to me.

We know that, "*Any subset of a countable  set is either empty, finite or countable"*. So, we know that, from the definition of $B_n,$ that $B_n$ must be either empty, finite or countable. If $B_n$ is countable  then there is no problem as we can label the elements of $B_n=\{b_{n1},b_{n2},b_{n3},...\}$ and proceed just like above to establish a $1-1$ correspondence between $\Bbb N$ and $B_n.$

But, the problem comes, when $\exists B_n$ such that $B_n$ is not countable, i.e $B_n$ is  finite or empty. I think this is the point where the argument in the given proof breaks down or better say, becomes ambiguous. I am looking for an explanation of this part of the  argument in the proof (, if at all it's a valid one) ?

I suggest modifying that part of the proof as follows:

> We again arrange the $B_n's$ with $B_1=A_1,$ just like we arranged it in case of disjoint $A_n's.$ To make things clear, we label the elements of $B_1$ as $B_n=\{b_{n1},b_{n2},...\}.$ One thing to note here, is that if $B_n\subset A_n$ is a finite set, then the set $\{b_{n1},b_{n2},...\}$ terminates somewhere and we don't bother with this happening.  If $B_n=\emptyset$ then, we just leave the corresponding row of $B_n$ i.e the $nth$ row blank and proceed to the next line. The arrangement will look something like this:
>
> $$B_1 = b_{11}\space b_{12}\space b_{13}\space ···$$
> $$B_2 = a_{21}\space a_{22}\space ···$$
> $$B_3 = a_{31}\space  ···$$
> $$.$$
> $$.$$
> $$.$$
>
> Here, the $2nd$ or/and $3rd$ row, might as well be terminating (or better say, finite) or might be blank.
>
> Next, we map the natural number $n$ in the $ith$ row and $jth$ column to the number in the $b_{ij}$ in our new arrangement ( of elements of $B_n$ ) provided $b_{ij}$ exists.
>
> This implies, that there are  some natural numbers which aren't mapped anywhere. We delete those natural numbers from the natural number arrangement i.e
>
> $$\begin{array}{}1& 3& 6&10&15\\
> 2& 5& 9& 14&\ddots\\
> 4&8&13&\ddots\\
> 7&12&\ddots\\
> 11&\ddots
> \end{array}$$
>
> So, we get a countable subset of $\Bbb N,$ say $P$ which is mapped to the elements of $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ and we denote this mapping as $\phi.$ Now, we note that $\phi:P\to \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is a bijection.
>
> We know that,
>
> Any infinite subset of natural numbers is countable. So,  this means, that $\exists$ a bijective mapping $\psi:\Bbb N\to P.$ Thus, $$\phi\circ\psi:\Bbb N\to \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$ is a bijective mapping as well$$\implies$$ $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is countable.

Is the above argument a valid one? If there are any errors please do let me know.

Finally, I feel that this above argument should be replaced with that portion of the original proof. I want to know whether this will make the proof  better or not?

Comment: This is just a terminology problem, coming from the fact you have excluded finite/empty sets from the definition of countable. You can do exactly the same construction for a sequence of $A_n$ that are countable (in your definition), empty or finite and everything will work flawlessly.

Comment: Another way to fix this would be to align all the $A_i$ and $a_{ij}$ first, then start populating your $\Bbb N$ grid in increasing order, taking care to _skip a spot_ (or equivalently _repeat the relevant number_) whenever you hit an $a_{ij}$ that you have already seen.

Comment: @Zanzag This terminology is not mine. The book only uses this definition of a countable set. And, the point where you say, "You can do exactly the same construction for a sequence of $A_n$ that are countable (in your definition)" ,well, if you read my post, then I already said that *I can.* For the remining part of the sentence (in your comment that I am quoting), "empty or finite and everything will work flawlessly", I want to (again) say that this is my question (if you read  my post). I want to know, how the argument in the given proof works if $\exists A_n$ such that it's finite/empty.

Comment: @Arthur I don't happen to understand your comment. It would be really helpful if you elaborate it in a maybe, simplified way, as the procedure you described as it stands in it's current version, seems to be a rather convoluted one, to me. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasFinley I think you are fixating too much in technicalities. You can do the same construction for a sequence $\{ A_n \}$ with finite or empty sets. You just numerate each $A_n$ as $a_{n1}, a_{n2}, \dots$. If the set is finite, you will have a finite number of indexes of the form $a_{nk}$ but this is not a problem.

You can then transform this enumeration into a standard one $a_1, a_2, \dots$ by traversing the enumeration (like is done here: https://cglab.ca/~discmath/figures/function-rationalscountable.png).

Comment: @Zanzag Maybe, I somehow get what you are saying but still it looks unclear. This part, "You can then transform this enumeration into a standard one $a_1,a_2,...$ by traversing the enumeration", confuses me. To be precise, I don't understand the meaning of the phrase "traversing the enumeration". It would be really helpful if you consider elaborating this portion.

Comment: @ThomasFinley That's what the author is doing when they say they arrange the elements in an array. You have an array of enumerations and you traverse it in a clever way to obtain a explicit enumeration $a_1, a_2, \dots$ (this is the function $g$ they introduce).

I suggest you do a small example yourself. Write down two copies of the naturals one below the other. How would you numerate them so each number has one (and only) index? If you also had a set $\{-1, -2, \dots, -k\}$, would you have any problem repeating the process with the extra (finite) set?

Comment: @Zanzag  You might want to check out my alternative argument. I added it in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I have reason to believe that the original statement of proof you mention is wrong and that it needs to be modified. So, here I will try to explain that statement from my POV and explain the small change it needs.

Original:
$$
B_n = A_n-\{A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_n\}.
$$
Changed:
$$
B_n = A_n-\{A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_{n-1}\}.
$$

Now to prove that this will fix the disjoint problem, lets say we have some $A_k$ and $A_{k+t}$ which have a non-zero intersection. Then through the above construction of $B_n$ we can say $B_{k+t}$ will definitely not have those intersection elements, since $B_{k+t} = A_{k+t}-\{A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_k \cup\cdots\cup  A_{k+t-1}\}$. Then we make that same array and see the one-one mapping.
$$
\begin{align}
B_1 = {}&b_{11}\space b_{12}\space b_{13}\space b_{14}\space b_{15} \cdots\\
B_2 = {}&b_{21}\space b_{22}\space b_{23}\space b_{24} \cdots\\
B_3 = {}&b_{31}\space b_{32}\space b_{33} \cdots\\
B_4 = {}&b_{41}\space b_{42} \cdots\\
B_5 = {}&b_{51} \cdots\\
&\vdots\end{align}
$$
Now, no element will repeat since every new $B_n$ makes sure that it doesnt have any elements which have already been covered in $A_1$ to $A_{n-1}$. Even if some sets have finite elements its just a matter of shifting the natural number row early, like so...
$$
\begin{array}{}
1& 3& 5& 8& 12& \\
2& X& X& X& \ddots \\
4& 7& 11& \ddots \\
6& 10& \ddots \\
9& \ddots
\end{array}
$$
So, even in cases of disjoints, we can make an injective function. Thus, If $A_n$ is a countable set for each $n \in\Bbb N$, then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n,$ is countable.